# React Native switch - save value as “Yes” / “No” instead of “true” / “false” in database

Tags: react-native

I want to save the switch value as **"Yes" / "No"** instead of **"true" / "false"** in database. Amenter code here using react native to fetching the values and storing in the database.

Please find my below code, that am trying.

```
this.state = {

colorFalseSwitchIsOn: false,

}
this.changeSwitch=this.changeSwitch.bind(this);

}
changeSwitch=(value)=>{

 this.setState({colorFalseSwitchIsOn:value?"Yes":"No"})




}
  render() {


return (
  <View>

    <Switch
      onValueChange={(value) => {
        this.changeSwitch(value);}}
      onTintColor="#00ff00"
      style={{marginBottom: 10}}
      thumbTintColor="#0000ff"
      tintColor="#ff0000"
      value={this.state.colorFalseSwitchIsOn}
      {...this.props}/>


  </View>
);
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: Its storing the default value "true" / "false" only. How can i change it to "Yes" / "No" value ?

Comment: Can you share the code which read and write values into database? The code that you have shared only store values into the state, which is I belive is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a const with "Yes" and "No" options, as shown below

```
const customBool = {
    YES: "Yes",
    NO: "No",
};
export myBool = customBool;
```

You can then re-use that constant in different components

```
import { mybool } from "/MyFile.js";
class Hello extends React.Component {
   makeYesOrNo(value) {
      return b ? mybool.YES : mybool.NO;
   }
   render() {
      let b = false;
      return <span>{ this.makeYesOrNo(b) }</span>;
   }
}
```

Or, you could create a class with boolean behaviours but with your desired Yes/No output

```
const customBool = {
    YES: "Yes",
  NO: "No",
};

class YesNoBool {
    constructor(shouldBeYes = false) {
    this.value = shouldBeYes ? customBool.YES : customBool.NO;
  }

  flip() {
    this.setValue(this.value == customBool.NO);
    return this;
  }

  setValue(newValue) {
    if (typeof newValue === "boolean") {
        this.value = newValue ? customBool.YES : customBool.NO;
    }
    return this;
  }
}
```

Your class could then work like this:

```
class myClass extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        myBool5: new YesNoBool(true),
    }
  }
  changeBool(newBool) {
    this.setState({myBool5: newBool});
  }
  render() {
    let { myBool5 } = this.state;
    return(
        <div>
          <p>Bool 5: {myBool5.value}</p>
          <button onClick={() => this.changeBool(myBool5.flip())}>Flip bool</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.changeBool(myBool5.setValue(true))}>Set true</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.changeBool(myBool5.setValue(false))}>Set false</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

See also [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Robb216/mqLdw6bh/27/) JSFiddle